# Add a web interface to access application logs

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using Logback in my application, and I will like some logs to be accessible through a web based console.

I though about starting an embedded Jetty inside my application and have a log-explorer webapp.

Is there any out-of-the-box solution for a similar task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/download) for viewing the logs through web

Comment: This is not what I was looking for although it is very useful. I am a looking to a logger which makes log available through a webapp